# delete max value from column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have problem when executed this code in CodeIgniter it deletes all records not only the max value record although it works fine if i execute Sql query in phpmyadmin what wrong in PHP code
my code:

controller:

```
            $this->data->del_data_query('DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE 
          sessions.name = 
            "dina" and id = (select max(id) from `sessions` ) ');

  Model:

  public function del_data_query($query)

  {

    $this->db->query($query);

  }
```

Comment: `select max(id) from sessions  limit 1`  doesn't need limit. MAX() function will return only a value if group by is not used

Comment: not working also. still delete all the record not the max

Comment: are you sure to compare s_id with max(id) ? these are two different fields

Comment: sorry my mistake in writing here they are the same i correct it , the problem from php only not execute all the query but if i execute query in phpmyadmin it works fine

Comment: are you using session database driver? Is this the table name in your config for `sess_save_path` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Also make sure that your id column is index = UNIQUE and is intiger

```
id = (select id from `sessions` ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 ) ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is correct: i tried it on my db.

Are you sure that, for some reason, your php didn't call del_data_query more than one times?

You could use some debug to test it, or more easily, add

`echo 'DONE';`

on end of method